# How can I manage an exclusive state in F#?

Tags: f#

I am not sure about "exclusive state management" thing in the title, I did my best making it up trying to put the problem concisely.

I am porting some of my C# code to F# trying to do it as idiomatic as I can. I have an entity that requests a number of ID's from a sequence in my database and then dispenses these ID to anyone in need. Once an id is given out it should no longer be available for anybody else. Hence there must be some sort of state associated with that entity that keeps track of the remaining number of IDs. Since using a mutable state is not idiomatic, what I can do is to write something like this:

```
let createIdManager = 
  let idToStartWith = 127
  let allowed = 10
  let givenOut = 0
  (idToStartWith, allowed, givenOut)
-
let getNextAvailableId (idToStartWith, allowed, givenOut) = 
  if givenOut< allowed
  then ((idToStartWith, allowed, givenOut+ 1), Some(idToStartWith + givenOut))
  else ((idToStartWith, allowed, givenOut), None)

let (idManager, idOpt) = getNextAvailableId createIdManager()
match idOpt with
| Some(id) -> printf "Yay!"
| None -> reloadIdManager idManager |> getNextAvailableId
```

This approach is idiomatic (as far as I can tell) but extremely vulnerable. There are so many ways to get it messed up. My biggest concern is that once an id is advanced and a newer copy of id manager is made, there is no force that can stop you from using the older copy and get the same id again.

So how do I do exclusive state management, per se, in F#?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to initialize the set of ids once then you can simply hide a mutable reference to a list inside a local function scope, as in:

```
let nextId =
    let idsRef = ref <| loadIdsFromDatabase()
    fun () ->
        match idsRef.Value with
        | []        -> 
            None
        | id::ids   ->
            idsRef := ids
            Some id

let id1 = nextId ()
let id2 = nextId ()
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid mutables?

Comment: It depends on your interface. You could simply load the list and pass around the ids. If you don't know upfront how many consumers you'll have it's trickier. Can you describe the requirements a bit more in detail?

Comment: I have only on consumer per a segment of IDs. The problem is that I dont see how exposing ids by passing them around can be made foolproof by making it impossible to acquire the same id more than one time.

Comment: If you could initialize the consumers with one id each, by mapping over the loaded list of ids, then at least you'd know that different consumers would not have access to each others ids. On the other hand there's nothing stopping a consumer from using the same id twice. Are the ids themselves important or do they just provide means to access some other functionality. In the latter case you could try to model the problem differently and removing the need for acquiring ids in the first place.

Comment: I think a downvote here is quite unwarranted. You want state that changes, but want to avoid mutation? A little critical thinking here goes a long way... ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn as was shown in my example a state without mutation is perfectly doable thing at a cost of some complications which I wish I could avoid

Comment: @bonomo : Your example only demonstrates getting the initial id, not how you maintain which ids are used/which is next. I.e. it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @ildjarn, my example shows getting the initial id and all subsequent ones dealing with the state that changes without mutation which you questioned in you previous comment, now if there wasn't a problem to solve with it there wasn't a question in the first place. Thus I have asked how this sort of situation is supposed to be treated in a purely functional way. (what would you do in Haskell) How hard is that?

Comment: @bonomo : In Haskell you would use mutable state in the form of a monad. And your code does _not_ show getting subsequent ids - you have a single id manager which you never update.

Comment: @ildjarn, line #8 `then ((idToStartWith, allowed, givenOut + 1), Some(idToStartWith + givenOut))` updates (creates an updated copy of the id manager) by incrementing givenOut by one

Comment: @bonomo : The implementation of `getNextAvailableId` is not relevant; how you _call_ said function and maintain the state it returns is what's important, and you haven't demonstrated that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a state-monad(Computational Expression).

First we declare the state-monad

```
type State<'s,'a> = State of ('s -> 'a * 's)

type StateBuilder<'s>() =
  member x.Return v : State<'s,_> = State(fun s -> v,s)
  member x.Bind(State v, f) : State<'s,_> =
    State(fun s ->
      let (a,s) = v s
      let (State v') = f a
      v' s)

let withState<'s> = StateBuilder<'s>()
let runState (State f) init = f init
```

Then we define your 'IdManager' and a function to get the next available id as well as the new state after the execution of the function.

```
type IdManager = {
  IdToStartWith : int
  Allowed : int
  GivenOut : int
}

let getNextId state = 
  if state.Allowed > state.GivenOut then
    Some (state.IdToStartWith + state.GivenOut), { state with GivenOut = state.GivenOut + 1 }
  else
    None, state
```

Finally we define our logic that requests the ids and execute the state-monad.

```
let idStateProcess =
  withState {
    let! id1 = State(getNextId)
    printfn "Got id %A" id1

    let! id2 = State(getNextId)
    printfn "Got id %A" id2

    //...

    return ()
  }

let initState = { IdToStartWith = 127; Allowed = 10; GivenOut = 0  }

let (_, postState) = 
  runState 
    idStateProcess 
    initState //This should be loaded from database in your case
```

Output:

```
Got id Some 127
Got id Some 128
```